# Restoring previous value of PGF/TikZ key?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys, tikz-styles

How does one restore the previous value of a PGF/TikZ key?

For example, I would like to set the `inner sep` of a matrix to `0em` but set the `inner sep` of nodes within the matrix to be the value that existed just before the matrix was drawn.  I thought that the following would work.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw}]
  \pgfkeysgetvalue{/tikz/inner sep}{\previnnersep}
  \matrix [matrix of nodes, inner sep=0em,
           cells={inner sep=\previnnersep}] {
    X & Y \\ };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

However, it produces output as if `inner sep=0em` were never included; this is certainly unexpected:

[image: matrix with inner sep not set to 0em, surprisingly]

Even more startlingly, when I change the `cells` option to be `cells={inner sep=1em}` but leave the `\pgfkeysgetvalue` line included, the output is exactly as before --- the same as if `inner sep=0.3333em` were used everywhere!

This odd behavior seems to originate from the `\pgfkeysgetvalue` line because everything is as expected when I comment it out.

*Why is this happening, and how can I achieve the desired behavior?*

Comment: Inner sep is not a value-storing key.  It is an alias that further sets inner xsep and inner ysep.  So you'd need to grab one of them.

Comment: @AndrewStacey You are right. Be sure to use the `/pgf` prefix: `/pgf/inner xsep` and `/pgf/inner ysep`.

Comment: @PolGab Indeed, if I try the `/tikz` prefix instead of `/pgf`, I get the error "Undefined control sequence. `\pgfmath@dimen@ ...men@@ #1=0.0pt\relax \pgfmath@`"  However, since page 176 of the 2.10 manual says that `/tikz/inner xsep` is an alias for `/pgf/inner xsep`, I'm curious why it is necessary to use `/pgf` for this to work.

Comment: @AndrewStacey In that case, why does `\pgfkeysgetvalue{/tikz/inner sep}{\previnnersep}` not give some sort of error instead of the very odd behavior?  Trying to use `\pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgf/inner sep}{\previnnersep}` does give an error, though.

Comment: Because `/tikz/pgf` is not actually an alias, it isn't defined.  When you call it, pgfkeys passes unknown tikz keys on to pgf so it is effectively an alias.  But getting its value uses a different mechanism to calling so it doesn't notice the alias.

Comment: Why don't you just group the setting here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on the comments by Andrew Stacey and PolGrab, you could create a style that achieves the effect you describe:

```
\tikzset{cells preserve inner sep/.style={
    cells/.expanded={
        inner xsep=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep},
        inner ysep=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner ysep}
    }
}}
```

Then use it like this (the order is important):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw}]
    \matrix [matrix of nodes, cells preserve inner sep, inner sep=0em] {
        X & Y \\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Result:

[image: cells preserve inner sep]

Answer (score 4):

A re-arranged approach is:

```
\tikzset{matrix style/.style={
  cells/.expanded={
    inner xsep=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep},
    inner ysep=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner ysep}
  },
  matrix of nodes, inner sep=0em
}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw}]
    \matrix [matrix style] {X & Y \\};
\end{tikzpicture}
```