# tikz matrix: width of a column used as spacer

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

I want to insert text in a beamer slide using an invisible tikz matrix of fixed width (`.85\paperwidth`), 2 columns (~ 3cm) on the upper left part and similarly on the upper right part. Only one matrix, with a middle empty column used as spacer. This way the two blocks will be symmetrically placed.

The main problem is the calculation of the width of the middle column. I thought of setting `minimum width = .8\paperwidth` for the matrix settings and setting the width of col. 1,2,4,5 individually would automatically adjust the width of the middle column so that the whole matrix width is equal to my setting, but that does not work. Also I've not been able to setup the use of `width("x")` for setting the width of columns 1,2,4,5.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newlength{\slw}\setlength{\slw}{160mm}
\newlength{\slh}\setlength{\slh}{100mm}
\geometry{verbose,papersize={\slw,\slh}}

\usepackage{tikz,calc,xfp}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix}
  \tikzset{
  allmatrix/.style = {matrix of nodes, rounded corners = 1mm,
                      nodes in empty cells,matrix anchor=#1,
                      row sep=-\pgflinewidth, column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
                      ampersand replacement=\&, nodes={outer sep=0pt},
                      text height=1.5ex, text depth=.25ex},
  table/.style args= {#1/#2}{
        column #1/.append style={nodes={align=left,
        minimum width={\fpeval{#2 + 2 * 2mm}pt}, text width=#2}},
        }}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]

\matrix at (current page.north)
[shift={(0,-2)}, allmatrix=north, nodes={draw},
table/.list={1/3cm,
             2/3cm,
             4/3cm,
             5/3cm}] (mytab)
% table/.list={1/width("le monde"),
%              2/width("new york times"),
%              4/width("le figaro"),
%              5/width("southern echo")}] (near)
{
le monde \& new york times  \& \& le figaro \& southern echo\\
innadu   \& le maine        \& \& penpavar  \& the hindu \\
times    \& spectrum        \& \& science   \& nature \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't use `\fpeval`. Just use `#2+2*2mm` directly. PGF/TikZ evaluates that on its own. Instead of `2mm` use `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}`.

Comment: Instead of an empty middle column (which needs to have something in it otherwise it has no width) you can just set the column sep between column 2 and 3 to the remainder of the width: `.85\paperwidth` minus all the text widths minus all the inner xseps.

Comment: since i use a list to pass the width of the columns, how would you express that calculation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `\fpeval` unless you really need it (and it doesn't understand `width("…")` which is a PGFmath function). PGF/TikZ throws almost everything in PGFmath anyway so there's no need for another package to evaluate things (unless you need high precision).

In the code below, I've removed the setting of `minimum width` completely since `text width` already specifies the width of the nodes. PGF just adds the value of [`/pgf/inner xsep`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#pgf/inner:xsep) on both sides.

Instead of a pseudo-empty column I'm choosing to set the column sep between the second and the third column (out of four). For this, I preset the value-key `/tikz/user1850133 column sep` with `.85\textwidth` and inside the `table+/.list` execution the `width("…")` as well as twice the inner xseps will be subtracted. (To be precise I'm just building a value of

```
.85\textwidth-width("le monde")-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}-
             ⋮
             -width("southern echo")-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}
```

The actual evaluation is done by PGFmath somewhere deep in the building of the matrix.

(The calculation possibly needs `()` around `\pgfkeysvalueof{…}` if that contains more complex values than the default `.3333em`.)

---

I've added

```
every outer matrix/.append style={inner sep=+0pt, outer sep=+0pt}
```

so that [the actual matrix is as tight as possible](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/653533/16595) since the matrix itself has its own inner (and outer) seps.

I've also changed the down-shift to be `2cm` in the canvas coordinate system (instead of the *xy* coordinate system) because you only deal with actual lengths.

---

The second frame is built by using two seperate matrices whose outer border is set `.85\textwidth` from each other. This would make it easier to create matrices that have different numbers of columns without having to figure out which one is the column before the split.

The output is slightly different, though I chalk this up to imprecisions of calculations of lengths and distances.

### Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\geometry{verbose,papersize={160mm,100mm}}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzset{
  allmatrix/.style = {matrix of nodes, rounded corners = 1mm,
                      nodes in empty cells, matrix anchor=#1,
                      every outer matrix/.append style={inner sep=+0pt, outer sep=+0pt},
                      row sep=-\pgflinewidth, column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
                      ampersand replacement=\&, nodes={outer sep=0pt},
                      text height=1.5ex, text depth=.25ex},
  table/.style args= {#1/#2}{
    column #1/.append style={nodes={align=left, text width=#2}}},
  table+/.style args= {#1/#2}{
    column #1/.append style={nodes={align=left, text width=#2}},
    user1850133 column sep/.append={-#2-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\matrix at (current page.north)
[shift={(0,-2cm)}, allmatrix=north, nodes={draw},
 column 2/.append style={column sep=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/user1850133 column sep}},
 user1850133 column sep/.initial=.85\textwidth,
 table+/.list={1/width("le monde"),
               2/width("new york times"),
               3/width("penpavar"),
               4/width("southern echo")}] (near)
{
    le monde \& new york times  \& le figaro \& southern echo\\
    innadu   \& le maine        \& penpavar  \& the hindu \\
    times    \& spectrum        \& science   \& nature \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\matrix at (current page.north)
[shift={(-.5*.85\textwidth,-2cm)}, allmatrix=north west, nodes={draw},
 table/.list={1/width("le monde"),
              2/width("new york times"),
              3/width("penpavar"),
              4/width("southern echo")}] (near-l)
{
    le monde \& new york times\\
    innadu   \& le maine      \\
    times    \& spectrum      \\
};
\matrix at (current page.north)
[shift={(.5*.85\textwidth,-2cm)}, allmatrix=north east, nodes={draw},
 table/.list={1/width("penpavar"),
              2/width("southern echo")}] (near-r)
{
    le figaro \& southern echo\\
    penpavar  \& the hindu \\
    science   \& nature \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Of course, the third column that is originally though to be the spacer can just have an empty path of horizontal length of `\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/user1850133 column sep}` but setting the `column sep` directly seems more natural.

Comment: your solutions and your explanations rock, though i do not get exactly what you have.

Comment: here the output i get for both frames: https://imgur.com/a/rNQSJMb

Comment: @user1850133 I can't reproduce this. Are you using an up-to-date TeX installation? It looks like some `width`s are evaluated by PGFmath to be slightly smaller than when TeX later builds a box. Did you change any font settings?

Comment: Though it should work with any font, the font, as displayed in the log at the end, is lmsans10-regular.otf. I copy-pasted your code without any change. I use lualatex (LuaHBTeX) 1.15.0. Tex Live 2022 (2022.8.12). Both lualatex and pdflatex give the same result.

Comment: @user1850133 Interesting, I get similar problems with LuaLaTeX but not with pdfLaTeX. This needs more research (possibly a PGFMath bug) but for a quick fix you could just add `1pt` or any other small enough value to the width of the node (and as well as a substraction to `user1850133 column sep`): `text width=#2+1pt` and `user1850133 column sep/.append={-#2-1pt-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}}`.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newlength{\slw}\setlength{\slw}{160mm}
\newlength{\slh}\setlength{\slh}{100mm}
\geometry{verbose,papersize={\slw,\slh}}

\usepackage{tikz,calc,xfp}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix}
  \tikzset{
  allmatrix/.style = {matrix of nodes, rounded corners = 1mm,
                      nodes in empty cells,matrix anchor=#1,
                      row sep=-\pgflinewidth, column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
                      ampersand replacement=\&, nodes={outer sep=0pt},
                      text height=1.5ex, text depth=.25ex},
  }

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]

\matrix at (current page.north)
[shift={(0,-2)}, allmatrix=north,         column 1/.append style={nodes={align=left,draw,
        text width={width("le monde")},
        }},
 column 2/.append style={nodes={align=left,draw,
        text width={width("new york times")},
        }},
 column 3/.append style={nodes={align=left,text width={.08\paperwidth},
        }},
 column 4/.append style={nodes={align=left,draw,
        text width={width("penpavar")},
        }},
 column 5/.append style={nodes={align=left,draw,
        text width={width("southern echo")},
        }}] (mytab)
% table/.list={1/width("le monde"),
%              2/width("new york times"),
%              4/width("le figaro"),
%              5/width("southern echo")}] (near)
{
le monde \& new york times  \& \& le figaro \& southern echo\\
innadu   \& le maine        \& \& penpavar  \& the hindu \\
times    \& spectrum        \& \& science   \& nature \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just a suggestion. As OPs uses absolut positioning, I think it's easier to place two independent matrices than computing the distance between columns. This is the code for my approach using CarLaTeX code.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz,calc,xfp}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix}
  \tikzset{
  allmatrix/.style = {matrix of nodes, rounded corners = 1mm,
                      nodes in empty cells,matrix anchor=#1,
                      row sep=-\pgflinewidth, column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
                      ampersand replacement=\&, nodes={outer sep=0pt},
                      text height=1.5ex, text depth=.25ex},
                      nodes={align=left, draw}
        }

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]

\matrix at (current page.north west)
[shift={(1.5,-2)}, allmatrix=north west, draw=none, 
    column 1/.append style={nodes={text width={width("le monde")}}},
    column 2/.append style={nodes={text width={width("new york times")}}}]
    (mytab1)
{
le monde \& new york times\\
innadu   \& le maine\\
times    \& spectrum\\
};

\matrix at (current page.north east)
[shift={(-1.5,-2)}, allmatrix=north east, draw=none,
    column 1/.append style={nodes={text width={width("penpavar")}}},
    column 2/.append style={nodes={text width={width("southern echo")}}}]
    (mytab2)
{
le figaro \& southern echo\\
penpavar  \& the hindu \\
science   \& nature \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]